# Printing simulink model to JPEG image

Tags: matlab, printing, simulink

I am trying to print a simulink model as JPEG image. Is it possible to set printframe for the same?

I am using following command `print -sf14_new -djpeg -r200 abc4`. I want to use specific print frame? Is there any command that can do this?

Answer (score 1):

Check [Create a Print Frame](http://uk.mathworks.com/help/simulink/ug/start-the-printframe-editor.html) in the documentation, you need to use the [`frameedit`](http://uk.mathworks.com/help/simulink/slref/frameedit.html) function. There is a lot more stuff about printing in the documentation under [Print and Export Models](http://uk.mathworks.com/help/simulink/print-and-export-models.html), I strongly suggest you have a read.